# CLI documentation generator tool for RAML v1.0

Tags: php, node.js, command-line-interface, raml

Is there a functioning CLI document generation tool (RAML to HTML for example) which supports RAML v1.0? Currently, all the tools I found (such as raml2html, don't support v1.0.

Am I missing something, or is RAML 1.0 very common for describing API endpoints and yet there are no tools supporting it? It doesn't make sense to me. If RAML is not the de facto language for describing endpoints, then what is?